# Turn down the opacity of the whole website apart from one element onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have inserted a modal popup into my website. This is going to hold a image map that will act as the nav bar.

When this modal pops up I am keen for the rest of the website to "fade out" by reducing the opacity. I have already played around with body{opactiy:0.2;} but unfortunately this also reduces the opacity of the modal/nav image.

The long way round would be to change the opacity of every single element on the webpage, apart from the model, on a onclick....this seems like a difficult way to solve the problem.

Does a neater solution exist?

Thank you for taking the time to read my query.

Comment: I attempted to use !important to set the opacity of the nav to 1, but unfortunately it was still affected by the body opacity being set to 0.2

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a semi-transparent overlay behind your popup and in front of the page content, just like almost every website does? https://jsfiddle.net/x7jfr8a4/

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion would be to have a semi-transparent overlay over BODY, and have the model sit on top of this overlay.

But if you would like a quick fix: ***:not(#modal){opacity: 0.2;}**

Comment: so 

body:not(#modal){opacity: 0.2;}

I'll give this a try.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, no, you don't want to target the body, but it's children, so either *:not(#modal){opacity: 0.2;} or body *:not(#modal){opacity: 0.2;}

Comment: Hi. If this comment/answer or any other one solved your issue, please upvote/mark it as accepted :)